# Annuity: interest conversion more frequent than payment

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

> Gus deposits 25 into a bank account at the beginning of each 3-year
> period for 18 years (i.e. there is no deposit in year 18). The account
> credits interest at an annual effective rate of interest of i. The
> accumulated amount in the account after 18 years is X, which is four
> times as large as the accumulated amount in the account after 9 years
> (excluding the deposit made at time t = 9). Calculate X.

Correct answer: 652.23

My work:

$n$=total number of conversion periods for annuity term = 18, $k$ = number of conversion periods per payment period = 3

Then using equations for level annuities with payment period greater than interest conversion period, we solve
$$
25\frac{s_{\bar{18|}}}{a_{\bar{3|}}} = 4 \left[25\frac{s_{\bar{6|}}}{a_{\bar{3|}}} + 25\right]
$$

But I get stuck on solving for the interest rate, I get a polynomial with terms to powers 21, 9, and 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$X = 25(1+i)^{18} + 25(1+i)^{15} + \cdots + 25(1+i)^3 = 25 \require{enclose}\ddot s_{\enclose{actuarial}{6} j},$$ where $j = (1+i)^3 - 1$ is the effective three-year periodic rate of interest.  We are also given $$\frac{X}{4} = 25(1+i)^{9} + 25(1+i)^{6} + 25(1+i)^{3} = 25 \require{enclose}\ddot s_{\enclose{actuarial}{3} j},$$ where again $j$ is defined as above.  Therefore, $$4 \require{enclose}\ddot s_{\enclose{actuarial}{3} j} = \ddot s_{\enclose{actuarial}{6} j},$$ or equivalently, $$4 (1+j) \frac{(1+j)^3 - 1}{j} = (1+j) \frac{(1+j)^6 - 1}{j},$$ hence $4((1+j)^3 - 1) = (1+j)^6 - 1$, or $(1+j)^3 = 3$.  We ignore the trivial root $j = 0$.  Then to compute $X$, we simply substitute:  $$X = 25 (1+j)\frac{(1+j)^6 - 1}{j} = 25 \cdot 3^{1/3} \frac{3^2 - 1}{3^{1/3} - 1} \approx 652.233.$$

Answer (score 0):

After 9 years, the balance is $B=25\left((1+i)^9+(1+i)^6+(1+i)^3\right)$. After 18 years, the balance is $B'=25\left((1+i)^{18}+(1+i)^{15}+(1+i)^{12}+(1+i)^9+(1+i)^6+(1+i)^3\right)=B\left(1+(1+i)^9\right)$. We are given $B'=4B$ so $1+(1+i)^9=4$ hence $i=\sqrt[9]{3}-1$, and so plugging this into $B'$ gives the answer.

Comment: I'm confused about the expression $B(1+(1+i)^9)$, why is the plus one there, if we just want to convert the amt at t=9 to t=18?